# What is the influence of the nuclear leakage in Japan

Tags: nuclear-physics

[The recent news](http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/42044156/ns/world_news-asia-pacific/) says that

> Japanese authorities confirmed Saturday that radiation had leaked from a quake-hit nuclear plant after an explosion destroyed a building at the site.

What will be the influence of the nuclear leakage?

Comment: We all can read the news. And right now the news say: still mostly harmless :=(

Comment: Remember Chernobyl?

Comment: Yes, I remember, including the big difference in technology of the reactors. I'd recommend to wait what will happen. Panic in advance here in Europe or some other place far away is silly.

Comment: Nobody said anything about panicking @Georg. Besides technology has been known to fail before - Challenger, Columbia, Three-Mile Island, Bhopal, Chernobyl and the very latest ... Deepwater Horizon (the BP oil rig in the Gulf of Mexico). Its prudent to be aware of the possible outcomes.

Comment: Nice listing, Deepak. One case in India, all others in US, strange! Lets hope the Jepanese get off without big problems.

Comment: @Georg don't go reading meaning into something when there isn't any. I'm sure anyone armed with a computer and internet connection can compile a more geographically neutral list. I spent 2/3 of my life in India and 1/3 in the US. So its only natural that these two cultures would be the one's I have most knowledge of, no?

Comment: Of course, a geographical more objective list can be compiled. But a certain preference of US would remain. US have a tradition of not interfering in companys or general in private affairs. This includes security.

Comment: If you want a horrible ecological disaster affecting people from Japan google Minamata.

Comment: @dmckee, that is the opposite tradition: Interference in favour of companys. All this has two faces as any medal :=(

Comment: The number of people killed by radiation from these plants (I expect zero) will be far less than the number of people killed because of the lack of electric power. If paranoia makes them delay restarting the plants it will cause that much more problems. The alternatives to nuclear power cause more damage during earthquakes. Look for the photos of the oil plant on fire and the dam that broke. (And by the way, modern nuclear plant designs fail safe.)

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** I hear on the radio that there has been further damage that may effect the containment structure itself. This has the potential (if a series of additional things go wrong) to be rather worse than my original response implies. I haven't heard enough to even guess what might be involved.

---

I don't like the word "leak" in this context as it implies a passive failure. Steam---steam that had been slightly activated by proximity to the core---was intentionally vented, under controlled conditions to prevent a larger scale failure.

---

On the global scale the impact will be trivial: a increase in the extant radiological background that will be difficult or impossible to measure.

On the local scale the increase will presumable be measurably for a time, but will still be small compared to the natural background (see below).

On the political front the incident will be used as an argument against nuclear power plants by people who don't realize the a coal plant releases more radioactive material than that *every day it operates* (simply by dispersing the naturally occurring radiologicals that used to be safely buried with the coal).

---

The average resident of a technologically developed nation receives a does of roughly $1\text{ mrem/day}$ day-in and day-out for their entire lives. About half of this is the cosmic ray background. Another big chuck is naturally occurring radioactive materials (K-40, U-238 and daughters, C-13...). There is a measurable background related to above-ground nuclear detonations, a little from medical and dental x-rays. When we had CRTs all over the place they leaked a tiny little bit of x-ray.

In a few places the natural background is many times the average. Long term residents of these places live just as long as everyone else, and get just the same amount of cancer.

The altitude at which you live is usually the single biggest factor in determining your background dose, because the cosmic flux is strongly dependent on it.

Any panic about radiation should always be measured against these basic facts.

Comment: Yes. People tend to overreact to radiation alarms, because it is something not visible, like ghosts. Keep cool and wait for evaluation by the international atomic energy people, not what each random reporter spreads through half knowledge.

Comment: @dmckee you make some good observations +1. Just a minor quibble I have - coal plants have not been known to undergo meltdown leading to radiation poisoning in hundreds of thousands of people, birth defects in the generations to come and the destruction of arable land for at least as long as the half-life of whatever contaminant dominates in the fallout. Question is which is better - having the axe fall on your foot all at once, or to have your foot chipped away at with blunt scissors? I'll take the latter any day.

Comment: @Deepak: Reactor design has improved since they build a graphite pile in the squash coure. The Three Mile Island meltdown did exactly what it was designed to do: slagged out into a sub-critical mass inside the containment vessel and failed to poison anyone. Chernobyl suffered a chemically driven explosion because (a) the Soviets used a cheap design known to have critical failure modes and (b) the Chief Engineer decided to *experiment* with fast run-away scenarios. There is no cure for Stupid. In the mean time, coal mines kill people every year, and fly ash pile collapses poison ecosystems.

Comment: @dmckee *the Soviets used a cheap design known to have critical failure modes* - hindsight is 20/20. *Chief Engineer decided to experiment with fast run-away scenarios* Yes, there is no cure for stupidity - which makes an honest assessment of the possible consequences of "stupid" even more essential. And yes, coal and fly-ash pose grave environmental challenges. No argument with you there.

Comment: *"hindsight is 20/20"* Foresight was 20/20 on this matter in the US, Europe, and Japan. Designs of that type were not used *because* of the fire/explosion risk posed by the graphite. It is simply silly to count possible failure modes against nuclear power while failing to count *on-going* problems against traditional power generation.

Comment: Just heard on our evening news that the atomic energy committee of the UN was informed formally that the accident was of size 4 on a  scale of nuclear incidents going from 1 to 7. Also that they have established cooling with boronized sea water and it will take about a week to dump the reactor, which a reactor physicist said is normal time for this type of reactors.

Comment: Link for the scale anna talks about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Nuclear_Event_Scale#INES_Level_4:_Accident_with_local_consequences. Unfortunately that scale works on several dimensions at once, so it gives an ambiguous indication of how much or how widespread the damage may be. I.e. TMI was a level 5 because the core was damaged, but the Goiânia accident in Brazil was level five because people were killed.